# issues with getsitepackages under a virtualenv

Tags: python, terminal, virtualenv

I wanted to check out which Python interpreter was running under my virtual env so I just entered the virtualenv and used getsitepackages. This is what came out.

```
(test)~/Documents/Development/test$ python
Python 2.7.9 (default, Apr  7 2015, 07:58:25) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import site
>>> print site.getsitepackages()
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'getsitepackages'
>>>
```

Is this normal behaviour when operating under a virtualenv? If possible how would I correct, or should I even bother?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A user has the [same problem as you](https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/issues/228#issue-3378670).

There is a known bug, that [Python 2.7 isn't compatible with `site.py`](https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/issues/355). 
This bug is still open, since November 2012.

You have to leave virtualenv or use another version of Python.

Comment: 3 years and no fix? Ouch...does this issue persist if I use Python3?